# joomla article content splitting

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla article with a menu item that is linked to a category blog layout, that I want to show only

"**intro text**" and "**intro image**" when the "**read more**" has not clicked , but after the "**read more**" link is clicked. The intro text and image is hidden and those hidden content show only, does anyone know how to make this?

Thank you.

Comment: You've an option in joomla, post your content in editor, and select read more option where you want to split content, it will than show you an horizontal line depicting that content is splitted

Comment: hi Mr Alien , thx for your response on it, but what i am asking is that how can i hide (like toggle) both the intro part and full content part.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Joomla - go to the article with the intro text you want to hide and go to Article Options tab (Joomla 3.x) - the options are the right in older version (1.5.x); there is an option that says "Show Intro Text", you can select "Hide", and the intro text will be hidden when the user is looking at the whole article (after they click "read more").

If you want to do this for all of your articles, go to Content -> Article Manager -> Options and find the option Show Intro Text and set it to "Hide", then all articles will automatically have that setting applied to them.